# PHP DOM find div class and output html inside div

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is get the content HTML inside a div class but don't remove the HTML tags inside the DIV but remove the div query example remove class=test1 only.
Example HTML:

```
<div class="xx1">Some Extra Test<div class="test1">Test1<div class="test2"></div>Some Text</div></div>
```

I need the output to be

```
Test1<div class="test2"></div>Some Text
```

The PHP what I'm testing but this PHP code is deleting all HTML tags inside the div and is output only the text

```
 $html = '<div class="test1">Test1<div class="test2"></div>Some Text</div>';
 
 function DOC_Change_Data( $HTML = '', $Type = '', $Data = '', $Extra_Data = '' ) {
  if($HTML != '' && $Type != '' && $Data != '') {
   $doc                                                                                                              = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
   $doc->preserveWhiteSpace                                                                                          = false;
   @$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $HTML, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED); // @ if for suppressing warnings
   $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
   
   if(preg_match("#remove_only_tag#is", $Extra_Data)) {
    if($Type == 'query') {
     $nodes                                                                                                            = $xpath->query($Data);
    } else if($Type == 'getElementsByTagName') {
     $nodes                                                                                                            = $doc->getElementsByTagName($Data);
    }
    
    foreach($nodes as $node) {
     $prent                                                                                                            = $node->parentNode;
     $prent->replaceChild($doc->createTextNode($node->nodeValue), $node);
    }
    
    $GET_Node_Data                                                                                                    = str_replace("<?xml encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>", "", $doc->saveHTML());
    
    return $GET_Node_Data;
   }
  }
 }


 echo DOC_Change_Data( $html, 'query', '//div [@class="test1"]', 'remove_only_tag' ) . "\n\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach the issue by using xpath to select the target element, convert it to string and then use string manipulation methods to get to the desired output. It's a bit convoluted, but the code below should work for both html strings (the one in your question and the one in your comment); however, depending on the html structure, may have to be modified:

```
$html1 = <<<HTML
    <div class="test1">Test1<div class="test2"></div>Some Text</div>
    HTML;
$html2 = <<<HTML
    <div class="xx1">Some Extra Test<div class="test1">Test1<div class="test2"></div>Some Text</div></div>
    HTML;
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadhtml($html2); //or html1
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc); 

#get the right element using xpath
$node= $xpath->query('//div[@class="test1"]');

#convert the element to string
$target = $node[0]->ownerDocument->saveHTML($node[0]);

#now manipulate the string; it can be done in one step, but I broke it into two for clarity
$step1=explode('class="test1">',$target);
$step2 = explode('</div>',$step1[1]);
echo implode("", $step2);
```

Output in either case:

```
Test1<div class="test2">Some Text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `createTextNode` because by definition this is only text and will not contain `HTML` tags.

The correct approach should be:

1. You loop all the `children` of your `$node`. So in your case you have 3 children:

- The text element `Test1`
- The HTML tag `<div class="test2"></div>`
- The text element `Some Text`

2. For each of these children, you move them up 1 level: from being contained within your `$node`, to being attached to its parent. To do so, you `clone` the node, then you `insertBefore` to the `$prent`
3. You remove the initial `$node`

In code:

```
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $prent = $node->parentNode;
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $childNode) {
        $prent->insertBefore($childNode->cloneNode(true), $node);
    }
    $prent->removeChild($node);
}
```

This will output, as requested

```
Test1<div class="test2"></div>Some Text
```

Comment: I try using this html <div class="xx1">Some Extra Test<div class="test1">Test1<div class="test2"></div>Some Text</div></div> but i get <div class="xx1">Some Extra TestTest1<div class="test2"></div>Some Text</div> but i need to get still only Test1<div class="test2"></div>Some Text , how i can fix this to? Thank you!